# Add iOS device to Xcode's devices for debugging/building without cable

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to add an iOS device and enable the 'Connect via network' option for an that device in Xcode without first connecting the device to the computer with a lightning cable.

My situation is that both of my USB ports are broken so I can't connect any device to my computer via a lightning cable.

By the way, wifi syncing is already enabled on my computer for one of my iOS devices, the one I'd also like to use for wireless debugging on Xcode. I don't know if that helps at all..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, see the picture it must be found first in devices:

[image]

What type of computer is it? Potentially if you have a thunderbolt port, you could buy or even borrow a thunderbolt to USB adapter. I have one such for an iMac 2011 to convert thunderbolt 2 to usb 3. Any Mac from mid 2011 onwards including MacBook Air, pro or iMac should have it. I know it might sound expensive, but these days the adapters can be had cheaper.

Here is a link to the one I have on Apple Store and can confirm it works, and it might be useful anyway.

[Kanex Thunderbolt to eSATA + USB 3.0 Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HGC82ZM/A/kanex-thunderbolt-to-esata-usb-30-adapter?fnode=8b&fs=fh%3D4595%252B401f%252B4506)

And if after using it, you don't like it, Apple usually have a 14 day return policy.

Comment: It's an early 2011 MBP. Unfortunately my thunderbolt port is broken as well. I don't know how this happened :) I was hoping that there would be a way to manually add the device by maybe messing with Xcode's device configuration files.. if such a thing exists!

Comment: Unless you back your Mac up to a machine with a working USB and then restore it...and do it that way, I doubt you have many options. I suppose you could take the hard drive out and pair your devices in Xcode WiFi on a working MacBook...